# Why do oscillating sequences diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The sequence I'm presented with is defined by

$$a_1=3,$$ $$ a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{a_n-1}$$

I see that the values of this sequence are $$3, \frac{3}{2},3, \frac{3}{2},3,...$$

So they oscillate between 3 and 3/2. Why is this sequence divergent and not convergent?

Comment: For every candidate $c$, there are arbitrarily large indices $n$ such that $\lvert a_n - c\rvert > \frac{1}{2}$. So the sequence does not converge to $c$.

Comment: What definition of convergence do you know? Usually, if a sequence converges there is a single value and not a list of values with more than one option.

Comment: Be careful about your terminology - in a lot of circumstances, 'divergent' is _not_ the same as simply 'not convergent'; the former can imply, for instance, that a sequence $\{a_n\}$ is unbounded as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: The way I like to think of it is that a sequence converges if every subsequence converges to the same value.

Answer (score 18):

"Diverge" doesn't mean "grow big": it means "doesn't converge". In this case your sequence clusters around the two separate points $3$ and $3/2$, called *limit points*, rather than converging to a single point.

In the typical calculus setting, the behavior of a limit like $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2$ would be more appropriately viewed as *converging* to $+\infty$ rather than as *diverging*, although for whatever reason this point of view isn't taught in introductory courses.

Comment: *"Diverge" ... means "doesn't converge"* - which is really unfortunate terminology, because in a non-mathematical context, "diverge" denotes that things are moving apart. "Converge" matches up great with non-mathematical usage, but "diverge" is confusing.

Comment: @user2357112 The values *are* moving apart: there is a definite and persistent gap between them.  The fact that it's not growing doesn't mean the separation isn't there.

Comment: @RyanReich: If Ryan stands 5 feet away from Mary, and the gap is not growing bigger, I would not consider Ryan and Mary to be moving apart. Similarly, if Ryan and Mary walk in circles around each other, staying 5 feet apart, I would not say they are moving apart. If Ryan and Mary start 5 feet apart and walk towards each other, approaching but not reaching 3 feet apart, I would not say they are moving apart. The fact that analogous situations with sequences are described as divergent is just plain confusing.

Comment: I would not say that the terms of the series $a_n = n$ are "growing apart" either.  The fact is that the term means something different in math than it does in English and is suggestive enough that it's not incongruous when used as intended.  The point of jargon is not to be instructive, but mnemonic.

Comment: @RyanReich `The values are moving apart: there is a definite and persistent gap between them.` That makes literally no sense. That's not how English language works.

Comment: @Davor Good thing English isn't math then.

Answer (score 8):

Because 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n+1}=3
\text{ and }
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n}=\frac32
$$
and we have two subsequences convergent to different limits.

Answer (score 3):

A rather more verbose way to explain it:

In a sequence which converges to some limit (let's call it $L$), if you go far enough along the sequence (to large enough $n$), every number in the sequence from that point on is "close enough" to $L$. But what counts as "close enough"? Well, the whole point of convergence is that it doesn't matter. No matter what threshold you choose for "close enough", there is some point at which all remaining numbers in the sequence are "close enough" to $L$.

The sequence you're looking at doesn't have that property. If you try $L = 3$, then it's *not* the case that all numbers past a certain point are close enough to $3$. I could choose "close enough" to be "within $0.1$" (for example) and then you are stuck with an infinite number of $\frac{3}{2}$s that are not close enough to $3$. Or if you try $L = \frac{3}{2}$, it's the opposite: you're stuck with an infinite number of $3$s that are not close enough to $\frac{3}{2}$. Hopefully you can tell that if you try any other number as $L$, either the $3$s or the $\frac{3}{2}$s or both will not be close enough to $L$.

So the sequence doesn't converge. That's precisely the definition of a divergent sequence: one that doesn't converge.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know this:

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty }x_n=A \iff  \lim_{n\to\infty }x_{2n}=A= \lim_{n\to\infty }x_{2n+1}$$