# Why does every oscillating sequence diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

Is this statement true?

$$\bf\text{Every oscillating sequence diverges.}$$

My thoughts: $\bf{False}$. $s_n = (-1)^n$ does not converge. But it's bounded, therefore, not divergent either. Divergent means diverging to $-\infty$ or $+ \infty$, yes?

Solution key: $\bf{True}$. If a sequence oscillates, then its limit inferior and limit superior are unequal. If follows that it cannot converge, for if it converged all its subsequences would converge to the same limit.

Three other places discussing oscillating convergence:

1. [This website](https://www.superprof.co.uk/resources/academic/maths/calculus/functions/convergent-and-divergent-sequences.html) says: "Oscillating sequences are not convergent or
   divergent. Such as 1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7,..." I agree.
2. [This SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/994309) says: "Diverge means doesn't converge."  But, I
   think it can be neither?
3. [This SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1784507) says: "$\sin xe^{-x}$ is oscillating and
   convergent." I agree.

So, is the solution key correct? Who's right here?

Comment: (2) and (3) are right; The example in (1) only if you allow the limit to be $\pm\infty$.

Comment: It's a question of terminology, and the standard terminology (as far as I'm aware), is that divergence covers anything that doesn't converge.

Comment: Is the solution key correct?

Comment: @ElchananSolomon Could you point to some authority sources?

Comment: If you define divergent to mean "not convergent" (which is the usual definition in my experience), then the solution key is correct. The series does not converge to any limit, so it diverges. For example, the subsequence $s_{2n} \rightarrow 1$, but the subsequence $s_{2n+1} \rightarrow -1$, and since these subsequences converge to different limits the sequence $s_n$ cannot be convergent

Comment: @user13985 : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivergentSequence.html or https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divergent. I'm afraid that if you're expecting a Biblical or Constitutional authority on math definitions, you may be disappointed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I take Wolfram as the law of the land.

Comment: I note that both WA and MW agrees on the definition though, MW being slightly imprecise by not writing "a finite limit".

Answer (score 8):

You have to be very precise with your definitions. Generally, we call a sequence *divergent* if it does not converge. This means that convergent and divergent are each other's opposite.

As far as I know, there is no accepted definition for *oscillating sequence*.

The sequence $(-1)^n$ diverges, because it does not converge, while the sequence $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges to zero. Depending on the precise definition, you may or may not call the latter sequence *oscillating*, so you have to consult your textbook there.

Comment: Oscillation is a particular case of a more general one being a sequence with multiple "adherence" values (limit point in English ?) which is called divergent too.

Answer (score 4):

In the usual definitions that I have picked up from various instructors and textbooks, "this sequence diverges" just means "this sequence doesn't converge". You could self-consistently define things the other way, but this is unusual in my experience.

By contrast, "this sequence oscillates" is usually not rigorously defined. Thus when we somewhat casually say "this sequence doesn't converge because it oscillates forever" we really mean "this sequence doesn't converge because it oscillates *with an amplitude bounded away from zero* forever". With no formal definition setting the context, I would probably say that $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ both oscillates and converges.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your definition of oscillation of sequences.According to the Wikipedia page here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_(mathematics)#Oscillation_of_a_sequence, the oscillation is zero if and only if the sequence converges. So the answer key is correct because the difference between limit superior and the limit inferior is non-zero and hence the oscillation is non-zero, and so the sequence does not converge.